# .Net Core Transaction Another Dll

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

lib.ParamsInsert is called via another dll.
The transaction is rolled back when there is a problem with the throw statement. However, the operations in paramsInsert can not be undone.

In lib.ParamsInsert, there is a transaction in its own error.

```
                spcarikart.Repository lib = new spcarikart.Repository();
                using (var transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var result = db.Acenta.Add(obj).Entity;
                        var a = lib.ParamsInsert(db, new Params
                        {
                            Baslik = "Bahdir",
                            Deger = "1"
                        });

                        // ....Maybe Error other process

                        db.SaveChanges();
                        return result;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        transaction.Rollback();
                    }
                }
```

ParamsInsert

```
            using (var transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    var resul = db.Params.Add(obj).Entity;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    transaction.Commit();
                    return resul;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                    throw new Exception();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Does `paramsInsert` use transactions?

Comment: Yes, paramsInsert used transactions.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Do you mean you don't want to rollback `lib.ParamsInsert` when an exception is thrown in `//THROW`? Also (of-topic), don't use `throw new Exception();` in a `catch` block, simply `throw`. Although the whole `try-catch` is redundant there because after the `using` the transaction is rolled back when it's not committed successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They use different transactions. Don't start new transaction, as I see, you work with the same db context, so needn't start transaction in `paramsInsert`, remove `using (var transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction())` from it.

Comment: What do I do when I just want to run ParamsInsert?

Comment: @BahadırDemir you have one operation only - it's transactional by default

Comment: @BahadırDemir or you can pass existing transaction to `ParamsInsert` method and use it

Comment: I will have to write two methods for the usual operations